# after group by for one dataframe to generate a dictionary, how can I convert this dictionary back to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary `dict_1` like this

```
    '''
    {0: [1],
    1: [2,3,5],
    2: [1,2],
    3: [4,5]}
   '''
```

how can I convert it to a dataframe df like this:

```
'''
column 1 column 2
0        1
1        2
1        3
1        5
2        1
2        2
3        4
3        5
'''
```

my approach is `df = pd.DataFrame(list(dict_1.items()))`
but the output is

```
    0   1
0   0   [1]
1   1   [2, 3, 5]
2   2   [1, 2]
3   3   [4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be surely more elegant but is it something like this you're looking for?

```
for k, v in d.items():
   for e in v:
   print(k, e)
```